# How to write common custom GSON deserializer for all fields of a class?

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a class MySimpleObject that have various member fields. Given a json, it will populate the field accordingly. However if the json is stated as "nil", I plan to set it to null instead of string "nil".

The below example should result is an MySimpleObject with null for all it's fields, and a 0 length list of `subItemList`. `myObj1` should be equal to `myObj2`.

```
@Test
public void myTestFunction() {
    String myJson1 = "{\"item1\":\"nil\",\"item2\":\"nil\",\"subItemList\":[{\"subItem1\":\"nil\",\"subItem2\":\"nil\"}]}";
    String myJson2 = "{\"subItemList\":[]}";

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<List<MySubItems>>(){ }.getType(), new MyOwnListDeserializer());
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new MyOwnStringDeserializer());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    MySimpleObject myObj1 = gson.fromJson(myJson1, MySimpleObject.class);
    MySimpleObject myObj2 = gson.fromJson(myJson2, MySimpleObject.class);

    assertThat(myObj1.equals((myObj2))).isTrue();
}

class MySimpleObject implements Serializable {
    String item1 = null;
    String item2 = null;
    List<MySubItems> subItemList;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = 31*hash + ((item1 == null)? 0 :item1.hashCode());
        hash = 31*hash + ((item2 == null)? 0 :item2.hashCode());
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof MySimpleObject) {
            return this.hashCode() == obj.hashCode();
        }
        return super.equals(obj);
    }
}

class MySubItems implements Serializable {
    String subItem1 = null;
    String subItem2 = null;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = 31*hash + ((subItem1 == null)? 0 :subItem1.hashCode());
        hash = 31*hash + ((subItem2 == null)? 0 :subItem2.hashCode());
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof MySubItems) {
            return this.hashCode() == obj.hashCode();
        }
        return super.equals(obj);
    }
}
```

How to write the custom serializer without having to loop through each jsonObject and check for "nil" to set to null?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the Gson library and also the [gson-fire project](https://github.com/julman99/gson-fire), but none of them seem to allow for a real generic (and performant) solution.

One way to go is to systematically replace `"nil"` by `"null"` in the json string before passing it to the gson object. It is not very clean, but it is quite performant and could work.

Here is a basic method (must be refined):

```
public static String convertNil( String json ){
      return json.replaceAll( ":\\s*\"nil\"", ": null" );
}
```

Then use it like:

```
MySimpleObject myObj1 = gson.fromJson( convertNil( myJson1 ), MySimpleObject.class );
MySimpleObject myObj2 = gson.fromJson( convertNil( myJson2 ), MySimpleObject.class );
```

Comment: Thanks. I like your out of box thinking answer. My question is not very correct previously. I have modified it. Can you check if you could have the answer now? Thank!!

Comment: I tried your answer, it is also giving a good result. I upvote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I manage to come up with some custom deserialization that do the job as below.

```
@Test
public void myTestFunction() {
    String myJson1 = "{\"item1\":\"nil\",\"item2\":\"nil\",\"subItemList\":[{\"subItem1\":\"nil\",\"subItem2\":\"nil\"}]}";
    String myJson2 = "{\"subItemList\":[]}";

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<List<MySubItems>>(){ }.getType(), new MyOwnListDeserializer());
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new MyOwnStringDeserializer());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    MySimpleObject myObj1 = gson.fromJson(myJson1, MySimpleObject.class);
    MySimpleObject myObj2 = gson.fromJson(myJson2, MySimpleObject.class);

    assertThat(myObj1.equals((myObj2))).isTrue();
}

class MySimpleObject implements Serializable {
    String item1 = null;
    String item2 = null;
    List<MySubItems> subItemList;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = 31*hash + ((item1 == null)? 0 :item1.hashCode());
        hash = 31*hash + ((item2 == null)? 0 :item2.hashCode());
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof MySimpleObject) {
            return this.hashCode() == obj.hashCode();
        }
        return super.equals(obj);
    }
}

class MySubItems implements Serializable {
    String subItem1 = null;
    String subItem2 = null;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = 31*hash + ((subItem1 == null)? 0 :subItem1.hashCode());
        hash = 31*hash + ((subItem2 == null)? 0 :subItem2.hashCode());
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof MySubItems) {
            return this.hashCode() == obj.hashCode();
        }
        return super.equals(obj);
    }
}

class MyOwnStringDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<String> {
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return (json.getAsString().equals("nil"))? null : json.getAsString();
    }
}

class MyOwnListDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<MySubItems>> {
    @Override
    public List<MySubItems> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        List<MySubItems> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (JsonElement element : json.getAsJsonArray()) {
            JsonObject subObj = element.getAsJsonObject();
            MySubItems subItems = new MySubItems();

            if (!subObj.get("subItem1").getAsString().equals("nil")) {
                subItems.subItem1 = subObj.get("subItem1").getAsString();
            }
            if (!subObj.get("subItem2").getAsString().equals("nil")) {
                subItems.subItem2 = subObj.get("subItem1").getAsString();
            }

            if (subItems.subItem1 != null || subItems.subItem2 != null) {
                list.add(subItems);
            }
        }

        return (list.size() == 0)? null : list;
    }
}
```

I'm still not very happy that `MyOwnListDeserializer`, has to manually handle subItem1 and subItem2, despite they should have the same rule as defined by `MyOwnStringDeserializer`. But I just don't know how to apply `MyOwnStringDeserializer` to `MyOwnListDeserializer`.

Would be still open for other better answers than mine.

*Update* A more optimized answer could be found in 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39671580/3286489