# Can I apply a custom deserializer to within another custom deserializer for GSON

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

The below is a working code that helps to convert JSON in Object accordingly. If the String is `nil`, it will be treated as null.

There's 2 custom deserializer i.e. `MyOwnStringDeserializer` and `MyOwnListDeserializer`. I am not happy with `MyOwnListDeserializer` deserializer, as essentially what it is doing is in term of the String comparison to the rule defined in `MyOwnStringDeserializer`. But I just can't and don't know how to apply the `MyOwnStringDeserializer` into `MyOwnListDeserializer`.

Is there a way for me to do so, that simplify the `MyOwnListDeserializer`? Or even better if there's a way to use just a single custom deserializer and could still achieve the same result?

```
@Test
public void myTestFunction() {
    String myJson1 = "{\"item1\":\"nil\",\"item2\":\"nil\",\"subItemList\":[{\"subItem1\":\"nil\",\"subItem2\":\"nil\"}]}";
    String myJson2 = "{\"subItemList\":[]}";

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<List<MySubItems>>(){ }.getType(), new MyOwnListDeserializer());
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new MyOwnStringDeserializer());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    MySimpleObject myObj1 = gson.fromJson(myJson1, MySimpleObject.class);
    MySimpleObject myObj2 = gson.fromJson(myJson2, MySimpleObject.class);

    assertThat(myObj1.equals((myObj2))).isTrue();
}

class MySimpleObject implements Serializable {
    String item1 = null;
    String item2 = null;
    List<MySubItems> subItemList;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = 31*hash + ((item1 == null)? 0 :item1.hashCode());
        hash = 31*hash + ((item2 == null)? 0 :item2.hashCode());
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof MySimpleObject) {
            return this.hashCode() == obj.hashCode();
        }
        return super.equals(obj);
    }
}

class MySubItems implements Serializable {
    String subItem1 = null;
    String subItem2 = null;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = 31*hash + ((subItem1 == null)? 0 :subItem1.hashCode());
        hash = 31*hash + ((subItem2 == null)? 0 :subItem2.hashCode());
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof MySubItems) {
            return this.hashCode() == obj.hashCode();
        }
        return super.equals(obj);
    }
}

class MyOwnStringDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<String> {
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return (json.getAsString().equals("nil"))? null : json.getAsString();
    }
}

class MyOwnListDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<MySubItems>> {
    @Override
    public List<MySubItems> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        List<MySubItems> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (JsonElement element : json.getAsJsonArray()) {
            JsonObject subObj = element.getAsJsonObject();
            MySubItems subItems = new MySubItems();

            if (!subObj.get("subItem1").getAsString().equals("nil")) {
                subItems.subItem1 = subObj.get("subItem1").getAsString();
            }
            if (!subObj.get("subItem2").getAsString().equals("nil")) {
                subItems.subItem2 = subObj.get("subItem1").getAsString();
            }

            if (subItems.subItem1 != null || subItems.subItem2 != null) {
                list.add(subItems);
            }
        }

        return (list.size() == 0)? null : list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo, mate! Jokingly: "There's 2 custom deserializer i.e. `MyOwnListDeserializer` and `MyOwnListDeserializer`. I am not happy with `MyOwnListDeserializer`" Ummm... with which of the `MyOwnListDeserializer` are you not happy, the first or the second?

Comment: Stay minimal - delete the unnecessary code. hashCode and equals contribute nothing to the question you ask. Try to break your lines so that one doesn't need to hscroll to view it all.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Fixed the typo. You're right that the hashCode and equals are not related to the question. But without that, it will not work for the comparison (of the test)... I provide the complete codes that works, so that one could just copy paste to try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're looking for is [`JsonDeserializationContext.deserialize()`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializationContext.html#deserialize-com.google.gson.JsonElement-java.lang.reflect.Type-). Per the warning about how to cause an infinite loop, this invokes any relevant custom deserializers you've set up.

I believe replacing the initialization of `subItems` inside the loop with a one-liner `MySubItems subItems = context.deserialize(element, MySubItems.class);` will do the trick, leaving only that and the check around `list.add(subItems)` in the loop body.

Comment: Works well. Thanks!